# Problem with converting decimal number to binary with C as translation from python code

Tags: c

I tried to first write python code where everything works just fine but now when I am trying to put everything together without pointers and allocation of array nothing works as I want. I now know that number cant be represented in an array so I decided to control whether the rest from the division is zero or one than it assign string representation zero or one. --> warning: assignment to 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// IN PYTHON
// import math
//# 100100
// decimal_number = 36 (36, 18, 9, 4, 2, 1, 0)
// binary_number = ""

// while decimal_number > 0:
//   tmp = decimal_number % 2
//   binary_number = str(tmp) + binary_number
//   decimal_number = math.floor((decimal_number / 2))
// print(binary_number)

int main()
{
    int decimal_number = 4;
    int len_arr = 7;
    char binary_number[len_arr];
    int counter = 0;
    char tmp_s;
    while (decimal_number > 0)
    {
        int tmp_i = decimal_number % 2;
        if (tmp_i == 0)
        {
            tmp_s = "0";
        }
        else
        {
            tmp_s = "1";
        }
        binary_number[counter] = tmp_s;
        decimal_number = floor((decimal_number / 2));
        counter++;
    }
    binary_number[counter] = '\0';
    printf("%s", binary_number);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As you have added double quotes, the compiler assumes it to be a string which is char *(character array) rather than a single character. Replace `tmp_s = "0"` with `tmp_s = '0'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> warning: assignment to 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer

That's because `tmp_s` is declared to hold a single character and is, thus,  expected to hold a `character constant`(an **integer**-*numeric value of the character in the machine's character set*, written as one character within **single quotes**)...but the code is attempting to assign a `string constant` (a sequence of zero or more characters surrounded by **double quotes**--technically, an array of characters), referenced by a pointer, to this variable, here `tmp_s = "0";` and here `tmp_s = "1";`.

`tmp_s` should be assigned, the numeric value of the characters `0` and `1` ...`tmp_s = '0';` and `tmp_s = '1';`